# java multi-line string behave strange in rational function test

Tags: java, string, rft, ibm-rational

I just wonder why it act this way.

In IBM RFT 6.x version integrated with a eclipse IDE .
I run the follow lines to get a text output from another program.

```
String Text = "";
String Text_Value = "";

Text = (String) outputText().getProperty(".value");
Text_Value = (String) outputText().getProperty(".value");
```

the original output captured by  **outputText().getProperty(".value")** is

```
2011-09-27 19:11:05.996 [Process ID:0x00000000] show cpup sc11
************************************************************
 CPU0  Usage                    : 3.2%
 CPU1  Usage                    : 6.29%
 Smooth CPU Usage               : 4.65%
 Real CPU Usage                 : 4.65%
------------------------------------------------------------
 CPU Usage Sample Rate          : 2(s)
 CPU OverLoad Level[1]          : 10%
 CPU OverLoad Level[2]          : 20%
 CPU OverLoad Level[3]          : 90%
 CPU OverLoad Level[4]          : 95%
 CPU Peak Usage                 : 99.88%
 CPU Peak Usage Time            : 2008-10-31 20:12:54
------------------------------------------------------------
 The History Real CPU Usage     :
 No   %CPU   %CPU   %CPU   %CPU   %CPU   %CPU   %CPU   %CPU
 0     3.87   4.76   4.72   4.76   4.76   4.69   4.65   4.65
 1     4.69   4.65
************************************************************
```

and the strange thing happens here.
I got the string variable

```
Text = "\r\n2011-09-27 19:11:05.996 [Process ID:0x00000000] show cpup sc11"
```

and

```
Text_Value = "\r\n2011-09-27 19:11:05.996 [Process ID:0x00000000] show cpup     sc11\r\n************************************************************\r\n.....4.69   4.65
          \r\n************************************************************"
```

The Text_Value is exactly what I want but the Text is always be cut off here in "show cpup sc11".

the twoline is expected to do the same thing.

when i try other output of the program.This would not happen.The two variable is same.

Comment: You need to post code for this question to be answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a synchronization issue. Your `Text` is cut off because the control is not quite populated. By the time `Text_Value` line is executed, the outputText() object is populated fully, so `Text_Value` is not truncated. You could prove this by inserting a `sleep(10)` command prior to the `Text` line. Change the value 10 to whatever arbitrary number of seconds is long enough for the outputText() control to have been fully populated.

Comment: Thanks Tom. outputText() is a bit slow. When sleep(0.1) it still fails but sleep(0.3) could solve the problem.Thanks,you cool!